# Windows Server Authentication on SQL Server for Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: sql-server, vpn, azure

We are trying to expand our company network infrastructure to the cloud with Azure.
One of the things that we will be starting with is to replicate our Domain Controller to Azure as shown in the topology below:

[image]

Our networks will be connected with a Site-to-Site VPN connection. There will be multiple other servers that we will slowly migrate to the cloud. One of them is our database server, which hosts SQL Server. My question is, if we established the Site-to-Site connection, will it be possible to use the Windows Authentication to in the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) as we did before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as your SQL server is joined to the domain, and your VPN connection is up you will be able to use Windows authentication. The fact that the machine is in Azure does not change this, so long as you have connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And it also won’t make any difference if on my computer I use the on-prem DC for authentication and the SQL server authenticates against the Azure DC (if the Azure DC is replicated)?

Comment: This will work fine, so long as you are replicating succesfully

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for the input!